# how can i add shipping carrier column in admin page

Tags: magento-1.9

i'd like to add Carrier (shipping method_ column on magento admin pate
under magento > sales > shipments

i put this code in Grid.php

protected function _prepareCollection()

> ```
> {
>     $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
>     $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id =
> ```
>
> sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('shipping_method'));
>           $this->setCollection($collection);z
>           return parent::_prepareCollection();
>       }
>
> $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
>               'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
>               'width' => '80px',
>               'type'  => 'options',
>               'index' => 'shipping_method',
>               'options' => $shippingmethods,
>               ));

but What i want to be shown is carrier title....like UPS, USPS, DHL
that code show me bit different result tThx
n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
            $shippingmethods = array();
            foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier) {
                if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods())  {
                    if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
                        $_title = $_ccode;
                    foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method)   {
                        $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                        $shippingmethods[$_code]= $_title;
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'index' => 'shipping_method',
            'options' => $shippingmethods,
            ));
```

try above code. Hope it helps to get Shipping Title. Thanks

Comment: i did but it didn't work